# asp.net MVC model binding with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

You see my dilemma here.  It's with the binding x => property.Name.  So normally you would do something like x=> x.someproperty.  But I'm using reflection so I can't do it that way.  I tried a number of things.  Using the viewdata to find the property.  Doesn't like that.  Any thoughts on the matter?

```
foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>@(property.Name ?? property.Name)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => property.Name, new { @id = property.Name})
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? MVC already has an `EditorFor()` method that will generate an input for each property in your model (and it does it correctly)

Comment: Changing it to editorfor and I'll still have the same issue.  The name of the model property.  I'm dynamically building the html based on the model.

Comment: Your not understanding what `EditorTemplates` are and how they are used. If your main view is `@model MyModel` then to generate an input for each property in your model you use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` or `@Html.EditorForModel()`. The html will be generated based on the default inbuilt templates, but you can use custom `EditorTemplates` to generate the html you want (i.e to include both a label and textbox and associated Bootstrap styled divs.

Comment: But to comment on some of your existing code. Your generating a label element which does not act as a label (clicking on it wont set focus to the associated control). Your using `property.Name ?? property.Name` which is nonsense (how can the property name be null and if could be, why set it null again). Your attempting to set the `id` attribute of the textbox to the same value as it already has.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that before I just haven't changed it.   Not my code.  But that's pretty cool I didn't know the editorfor would generate all that content for you.  Makes life alot easier.  I've just seen examples of people using it the same way as a textboxfor.  Thanks.  I'll have to look into the editor templates to customize the look.

Comment: You have some options. Create a template for the type e.g.`string` which means every `string` property in your model will be based on that template (the template needs to be in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/string.cshtml`) or use the `[UIHint]` attribute on your property

Comment: Nice.  I'm going to give this a shot.  Thanks again.