# Display FullName in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

In my MVC5 application can get the Username in **_Layout.cshtml** page by using

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

I added new field to the table **AspNetUsers** called FullName but I cant't display it in _Layout.cshtml, It's show just Name!

[image]

How can I get FullName insted of User name in _Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay .. I solve it by using session to share FullName across all my application

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserFullName", UserFullName);
```

Then I can use it in everywhere

```
@Session["UserFullName"]
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for the question and solution, that 's what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by working with the user's Claims on `User.Identity`. When you handle your user's login, you should be able to retrieve the user's information from the database, including the FullName property you wish to store.

You cannot directly set this value to be what User.Identity.Name provides, however you can add a value to the collection of Claims and then retrieve that value when you need to. You will first need to cast User.Identity into a ClaimsIdentity instance, however.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var fullName = "Name From Database";
   var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
   claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", fullName));
   return View();
}
```

View:

```
@{
    var claims = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var fullName = claims.FindFirstValue("FullName");
}

@(fullName)
```

Both your view and your controller will need to import these namespaces:

```
using System.Security.Claims
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

Comment: I try your solution but in the view I got this error: (The type or namespace name 'ClaimsIdentity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

Comment: Ah, sorry. Resharper lets me tend to forget about using statements (it imports them for me a lot). You will need to import these into both your controller and your view. Check my edit, I've added it to the answer post.

Comment: Thanks for user help, I can pass the user FullName now, but I pass it from Index in home controller to _Layout.cshtml, when I open another page the full name does not displayed ! should I pass the full name from each controller !

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData or ViewData. I think u can use reflection. 
You can look this link.

[You can look this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282863/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-with-reflection)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126049/how-to-pass-model-in-mvc-view

Answer (score 0):

The solution above from "Abdulsalam Elsharif" worked fine with me, but I can't resolve HttpContext.Current in asp.net mvc4
so in controller:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserFullName", FullName);
```

and in view:

```
@Session["UserFullName"]
```